# After closing Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012, a strange document has appeared

Tags: steam, technical-issues, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012

When I closed the game, I found there was an open document on my desktop titled 'mother'. It has a bunch of text mentioning a card in the game (I was just playing Nissa's deck against Jace in Archenemy Mode, with another Nissa on my team).

Here's the text the document has in it:

```
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value  
[lua] [string "VIRIDIAN_EMISSARY_243010_TITLE (RESOLUTION_TIME_ACTION) [19027680]"]:2: attempt to index a nil value
```

I've never closed a game before and found a document open on my desktop that wasn't there before. What is this?
And no, my game wasn't experiencing any problems. This looks like an error log, but I have no clue why it would be on my desktop when I closed the game. Like I said, nothing went wrong, and I wasn't trying to bugfix anything, so this wasn't my doing.

Opening up Steam, I've found that the game is apparently still running, but clicking 'stop' does nothing, and the game doesn't appear in Task Manager! When I tried to turn off Steam, it told me that the game was still trying to shut down.
Forcing Steam to shut down via Task Manager closed Steam, and when I re-opened it the game was no longer listed as running. The document is still on my desktop though.

Just played the game again, I didn't get another document but the game refused to close in steam again. None of my other games are behaving this way. I'm tempted to do a complete re-start at this point.

Comment: Viridian Emissary is the name of a card, perhaps that can lead you closer to an answer with this issue.

Comment: I know that, and I thought I mentioned it?

Comment: My apologies, didn't see that. I'd imagine the AI was trying to play it or was trying to access it somehow. Maybe Jayce was trying to counter it or bounce it back to your hand but the game bugged out and didn't let that happen. All these MTG games create a ton of logs for everything.

Comment: A few Viridian Emissaries were played, but I don't recall anything odd happening with them. I don't recall him countering or bouncing any of them. Maybe the card draw just failed and I didn't notice or something. Who knows. I was more worried that my game may be broken.

Comment: Any chance it was trying to search the deck for lands but there were none or the deck was empty, so it had an error? "Attempt to index a nil value" is Lua saying the code told it to access an undefined property/value.